# Unable to update NULL via updateObject

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, sql

We got 2 tables where one table is parent and another table as a child with primary and foreign key reference.

Assume table1 is the parent and table2 is the child as below.

table1:

```
id  <- primary key of table1
name  <- name field
```

table2:

```
id  <- primary key of table2 auto increment
par_id  <- foreign key referring table1 default to NULL
position  <- posiiton field
```

The code snippet below is to update an existing record in the child table with par_id as NULL

```
$recObj = new stdClass ();
$recObj->id = '1';
$recObj->par_id=null
$recObj->position="test position"

$db->updateObject('#__table2', $recObj, 'id');
```

When the above code executes, it is not updating the par_id to null.  Instead the old value remains.

Answer (score 2):

Found a way by adding an another parameter as below:

```
$db->updateObject('#__table2', $recObj, 'id', true);
```

The 4th parameter determines whether null values can be used or not.  Default this will be set as false.

https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JDatabase::updateObject

Answer (score 1):

### The way it should be done

For now (until they introduce full entities support somewhere in Joomla! 4.x) it is better to use `JTable` to store "entities". In that way you can simply set `$updateNulls` parameter in `JTable::store()` method o `true`. It also simplifies a lot of CRUD and validate operations making your programming faster. You can read more in a [JTable documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JTable_class) or look for tables usage in core components.

### How to perform nulls update in updateObject()

The second method is to provide the fourth parameter to `JDatabase::updateObject()` method the way you did. As far as I remember it is used in `JTable::store()` internaly.

### If there is no API method for your case

As a last resort you can always run a direct query:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$db = Factory::getDbo();
$q = $db->getQuery(true);
$q
    ->update('#__table2')
    ->set('b = NULL')
    ->where('id=1');
$db->setQuery($q);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: "The way it should be done" does not work in all scenarios. In my case, setting $updatenulls to true does not update the value in the database (Maria 10.4). Joomla's (3.10) JTable uses the updateObject function of JDatabaseDriver. This function sets the null values to a 'NULL' String and passes the query to the execute function of the used db driver (JDatabaseDriverMysqli for me). The driver calls mysqli_query which does the actual update. Maybe some further configuration of the db server is needed to automatically convert 'null' to null. But I don't know that for sure.

Comment: @aProgger I have extensions working on MariaDB for years already and I did not have such issue with null values. So it might be the case it's your particular server configuration that's causing the issue.